# Sweden Personnummer

Tags: resident-permit, sweden

I'm a Pakistani citizen who has previously lived in Sweden for 3 years on permanent residence against my own self employment visa, but I have since moved on. The Swedish version of what is called social security number, social insurance number, government service number, or otherwise, is the personnummer. I got a personnummer assigned shortly after arriving and registering in the country. Does this personnummer remain valid for the rest of my life, or is there some expiry? How do I check the status of my permanent uppehalstilstand, which is the Swedish version of permanent residence? I have a sticker on my passport which says validity is indefinite.

Comment: Most countries have laws that provide for the automatic loss of a right of permanent residence after a certain amount of time absent from the country.  They don't have an automatic timer that starts every time you leave the country, however.  Rather, if some government official has reason to suspect that you've been absent, they'll give you an opportunity to present evidence to the contrary, and if you are unable, your permanent residence will be rescinded, independent of the expiration date of any document.

Comment: According to [this page](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_uppeh%C3%A5llstillst%C3%A5nd_i_Sverige), the permit is revoked if you move to another country, or stay outside of Sweden for more than one year. To find out I think you need to call _Skatteverket_ on the telephone. You cannot check it on the web.

Comment: The _personnummer_ itself will remain valid for life, but it is just an identification number. Having one does not imply anything about your legal status.